# Visual Studio 2015 Solution Explorer selected item color

Tags: visual-studio

Suddenly my Visual Studio 2015 Solution explorer window makes a selected item disappear.

It looks like the background is white and the font color is white, but I have changed the font, and color a few times, (tools>Options>Fonts and Colors>Environment), restarted etc.

When I first select a file or heading, the name disappears but there is a blue line above and below the selection and the icon is still there, when I then click elsewhere, like in the file itself, then the text reappears.

[image: invisible item on left pane]

On the left is when I just click on a filename, on the right it when I go to the file itself (or make any other window the focus)

How can I fix this?